# Unable to get the right average duration using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have created and log tool, which tracks Entry Created Date Time, Entry Start Date Time, Entry End Date Time.

How can I get an average , see below example

2 entries for an individual as below
00:04:21    and 00:21:04

I got these entries from  jquery code

```
<script>
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var pad = function (num) { return ("0" + num).slice(-2); }
        var totalSeconds = 0;
        var reslength = $(".totalColumn").length;

        $(".totalColumn").each(function () {
            var currentDuration = $(this).text();
            currentDuration = currentDuration.split(":");
            var hrs = parseInt(currentDuration[0]);
            var min = parseInt(currentDuration[1]);
            var sec = parseInt(currentDuration[2]);
            var currDurationSec = sec + (60 * min) + (60 * 60 * hrs);
            totalSeconds += currDurationSec;
        });

        
        var hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
        totalSeconds %= 3600;
        var minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60);
        var seconds = totalSeconds % 60;

        $(".showResTime").text(pad(hours) + ":" + pad(minutes) + ":" + pad(seconds) / reslength);

    });
</script>
```

Result using above jQuery code shows as 00:25:12.5 This is not correct

If we calculate this on Excel result is as follows
00:04:21 + 00:21:04 / 2 = 00:23:14 This seems to be correct.

How can I get the right average using jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your code to produce what you are looking for.  What was going on is that you needed to divide by `reslength` after you got your total seconds.

Also I don't think you are calculating average duration on your Excel file correctly:

```
 240 + 21  =  261      (time 1 total seconds)
1260 +  4  = 1264      (time 2 total seconds)
--------------------
1264 + 261 = 1525      (total seconds for both times)

1525 / 2   =  762.5    (average duration in seconds)
762.5      = 12 minutes and 42.5 seconds
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        var pad = function (num) { return ("0" + num).slice(-2); }
        var totalSeconds = 0;
        var reslength = $(".totalColumn").length;

        $(".totalColumn").each(function () {
            var currentDuration = $(this).text();
            currentDuration = currentDuration.split(":");
            var hrs = parseInt(currentDuration[0]);
            var min = parseInt(currentDuration[1]);
            var sec = parseInt(currentDuration[2]);
            var currDurationSec = sec + (60 * min) + (60 * 60 * hrs);
            totalSeconds += currDurationSec;
        });
        
        totalSeconds = totalSeconds / reslength;
    
        var hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
        totalSeconds %= 3600;
        var minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60);
        var seconds = totalSeconds % 60;

        $(".showResTime").text(pad(hours) + ":" + pad(minutes) + ":" + Math.ceil(seconds));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tg">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-0lax">Time 1</th>
    <td class="totalColumn">00:04:21</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-0lax">Time 2</th>
    <td class="totalColumn">00:21:04</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-0lax">Time 3</th>
    <td class="totalColumn">00:21:03</td>
  </tr>  
</tbody>
</table>


<h1 class="showResTime"></h1>
```

Comment: Thank you for quick solution and response. So, now in the above code I added one more entry as this 00:04:21 + 00:21:04 + 00:07:08 and with your code Result I am getting is 00:10:51.? Would this be correct. Kindly suggest

Comment: That would be correct.  Because total seconds would then be 1953.  You would divide 1953 / 3 and get an average seconds duration of 651 seconds, which equals 10 minutes and 51 seconds average duration.

Comment: thank you for sharing your valuable knowledge. Really helps to understand the calculation.

Comment: why am I getting time like this 00:14:17.33333333333337

Comment: @ EspressoBeans how can I fix this 00:14:17.33333333333337

Comment: Hi, I've updated the example above to have seconds to round up by using Math.ceil() which will round a number up to the nearest integer.

Comment: appreciate your help. How to avoid getting aN:aN:aN error .